# How to group(using set()) for every n elements in an array: python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I apologize if this question is already asked but i am not able to find the answer. 
I have a list of elements. I wanted to group elements for every 4 elements in the array.
Example:

```
my_list = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H",....]

result = [{"A","B","C","D"},{"E","F","G","H"},....]
```

Comment: Split into evenly sized chunks (see the duplicate) and make each chunk a set. Using the function from the top answer that'd be `[set(c) for c in chunks(my_list, 4)]`.

Comment: `it = iter(my_list)print([set(zip(it,it,it,it))])`, resuming all values are unique

Comment: thank you. Your answer is helpful